# Identify assembly code and creating a python script for it

Tags: python, assembly, arm, disassembly, ida

I am trying to understand this assembly code and create a python script to reverse it but i have some questions about it...

After trying to understand the code in IDA,
[Assembly code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7qS1.png)

[image]

I think the following is happening:

The image on the left is the previous part before entering on the function on the right. I have marked the interest part in RED.

First it loads the address of a important part of the DLL file (which is scrambled, ida does not recognize) in R4, then moves R4 to R0. And enters the function which im interested (right on the Picture).

I think that part is doing some unscramble of the code.

Correct me if im wrong, but i guess that there is a for loop in that function where R1 is the control.

R3 is the memory address + R1 (offset?)

R2 is the code to be unscrambled, it is shifted left Bitwise by a byte
then R2 is added by R3. (this part i am confused.)
Data followed by the address in a single register? Is this correct?

and then R1 is set to minus 1. This for loop stops when R1<0. So it runs 4 times.

It seems that it unscramble the code 4 bytes at a time.

I would like to build a python function where i send the data and it returns the unscrambled code.

Scramble example: 0xFF2B0092, 0x700055, 0x610064, 0x650074FB, 0xFF065300

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to (a) write an Assembler-"Emulator" in Python, or (b) create a Python program that does the same (e.g. add two numbers), or (c) create a Python program that does the same using the same methods (i.e. manipulating values in registers and stuff)?

Comment: Also, what would be the "unscrambled code" for your "scrambled example"?

Comment: I would like to simply copy the data from hex in a python script and get the data unscrambled. I dont know what in the scrambled part. I know there is something because there are some parts that are readable.

Comment: Sure, but how does that "unscrambled" data look like? What would the assembly code return for that input?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you question... What do you mean by "data look like"? I guess that if I get part of the readable text correct, i would assume that the non readable would be correct and then IDA could process the code and find more functions... IDA informs that code may have been obfuscated.

Comment: Something tells me that the loop is  just reversing the bytes order. Which does not means much...

Comment: *It seems that it unscramble the code 4 bytes at a time.*  That's because ARM uses fixed-width 4-byte instructions.  This is called disassembling one instruction at a time.  It sounds like you want to write an ARM disassembler in python.  Google that, using those search terms, to find more about writing disassemblers.